# Throwing custom validation exceptions/errors in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am upgrading Laravel from 5.2 to 5.3. In 5.2, I was throwing [`Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationException`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Validation/ValidationException.php) (using my own validation logic) like so:

```
$this->errors = new MessageBag();
...
ValidationException($this->errors);
```

In 5.3, `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationException` is removed. How do I keep the same blade output behaviour? Do I simply recreate `ValidationException`?

```
// In blade, this should still print error. (JSON should keep same behaviour too)
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```